# Dog’s loose tooth and gum

Tags: dogs, dental-care

Yesterday, my dog was running fast and then out of nowhere another dog came and they crashed into each other for just a second. Then my dog was acting like he wanted to take something off his mouth. There was also some blood but not a lot. Later on I checked his mouth and noticed that one of his upper incisors (the one pointed to in the picture) has came off but still in his mouth attached to a very loose piece of gum.

The accident made me so upset. I don’t know how could that have happened. Maybe the other dog bitted my dog right on the tooth? Or maybe their tooth crashed into each other? That was just a weird thing happening just in the course of a few seconds. My dog is about 11 months old. So still young and it is sad that he lost a tooth like that.

Now my dog is doing fine generally. Not that much in the playful mood as before, but he eat his food as regular. There is no blood anymore but he is a bit sensitive around his mouth and doesn’t like it when I touch around the tooth.

What would you do in a similar situation? I would like to check with a good doctor but I am not sure if I can find one where I live, or if the doctor can actually do anything about it.

Will the tooth fully come off by itself if I wait for a few days? What about the piece of gum that is also loose hanging in his mouth? Does it need surgery? I appreciate your view.

**Update: the loose tooth and gum is no more there. But still he is a bit sensitive around his mouth.**

[image]

Comment: Veterinarian. Immediately.